# python Joining Data frame

Tags: python, join, dataframe

Hi I have two data frames as below

```
df1:

User_id        time          Activity
1            1-1-2017 12:30     Impression
1            2-3-2017 10:30     Impression
1            5-6-2017 00:02     Impression
2            2-10-2017 05:09    Impression 

df2:

User_id        time         Activity
1            3-3-2017 11:30     Click
1            7-3-2017 10:30     Click
2            6-5-2017 00:02     Click
2            6-19-2017 06:10    Click
```

`df1` shows the users those who have got exposed to an ad and `df2` shows who have clicked the ad. I want to merge those both dfs in python such that I get the users that have atleast one impression before a click. Number of impressions before a click. difference between first impression and first click.

sampleoutput:

```
User  # impression timediff  
1        2          28 days
2        1          129 days
```

Please help me in the way to use merge function along with conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the difference between the earliest `impression` to `click` with:

```
>>> (df2.groupby('User_id').min()['time'] - df1.groupby('User_id').min()['time']).dt.days
User_id
1    60
2   114
Name: time, dtype: int64
```